# How much bonus experience do massacres grant?

Tags: diablo-iii

In Diablo 3 (PC) the patch 2.4.0 modified the way massacre bonuses worked to give a multiple of the experience you gain from kills during the massacre, instead of some flat amount.

The bonus lists something like "1.5x bonus experience!" Does this mean I get an additional 50% experience for those kills? Or does it mean I get an additional 150% experience for those kills?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The other answer is wrong (or incredibly unclear).

The massacre XP bonus only counts for the base exp which is why it's so abysmal in the later Torment levels.

https://www.reddit.com/r/Diablo/comments/40scd1/is_the_new_action_combat_bonus_xp_thing_in_24_any/cywq87s

> I explain the massacre bonus in my leveling guide and how it works. It
>   also only multiplies the baseline experience, so the multiplier is
>   additive to the existing bonus XP. Basically, it's really good for
>   leveling, not so much when you're TX grinding bounties. It also only
>   works in Bounties and does not work in Rifts and Greater rifts.

XP Leveling guide that the author of that comment wrote (and explains what his answer is in reference to):

https://www.reddit.com/r/Diablo/comments/3ziyyy/its_back_24_season_5_fast_leveling_guide_update/

Comment: What is the "baseline experience"?  The experience given on Normal!?

Comment: @BlackVegetable The experience given on normal, yes. Basically, in torment X you get some 3300% XP bonus or something. If you get the 4.5x multiplier from a ~300 kill massacre, you will get 3750% XP total, the extra 450% coming from the 4.5x multiplier working off the original 100%. Does that make sense? In essence, it's an additive bonus.

Comment: @Matthew my answer clearly states that "bonus xp" is set of addition xp given to the player and even links to the history of this mechanic, and the multiplier multiplies this xp, there's nothing wrong there.

Answer (score 1):

On console, the "1.5x experience bonus!" (the actual order of the words) means that the bonus experience from the massacre you just got is being multiplied by the said amount.

So you get an additional 50%, for a total of 150%.

This is because after getting a massacre, you would always get "bonus" experience, even in vanilla D3 PC days, but that bonus was very very tiny, so the D3 team re-worked this bonus to have a multiplier to it based on how large the massacre was (how many enemies killed in a row).

[This page](http://www.diablowiki.net/Massacre_Bonuses) covers the history of the massacre "bonus", but does not include the changes brought on with console, check [here](http://news.softpedia.com/news/Diablo-3-Ultimate-Evil-Edition-Changes-Massacre-Destruction-Bonuses-449923.shtml) and [here](http://www.diabloii.net/forums/threads/live-chat-with-diablo-3-console-uee-devs-1080p-xboxone.863264/) for that.

> The experience multiplier listed kept increasing as their kill streak increased during the Jar of Souls. Initially it was just 1.5x, and about every 15 more kills it went up another .25% [sic], making out at 3.5% [sic] as they finished the whole Jar of Souls event. Because console players need constant numbers and flashing lights and feedback…

Comment: It's not quite clear from your wording and the linked articles.  Are you getting 150% of the exp you gained from the mobs you killed to get the massacre, or are you getting 150% of the pre-2.4 flat massacre bonus exp?

Comment: @Troyen, the massacre bonus. In this context the word "bonus" means the XP you get from the massacre mechanic. That is what I was trying to explain, "Bonus" in this context has always meant a set of additional XP that is given to the character for completing a massacre chain. With 2.4 changes, the "Bonus" XP has a multiplier, that's all it really changed.